# "There's someone's at the door" or "there's someone at the door"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> "There's someone's at the door"
>   "There's someone at the door"

What does the second "'s" stand for, "is", "has", or it is a possessive or third person singular s?

Is it incorrect to say "there is someone at the door"?

Ps. I came across it in Touchstone 2 book. Sceenshot below:

[image]

Comment: You came across the first sentence in a learning book? I ask because it's utterly wrong.

Comment: Realy!! I searched a lot to find what is it. So I guess it is a misprint then. It is in Unit 10, lesson C.https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=8R0-V_H8EITpatmBqtAO&q=%22there%27s+someone%27s+at+the+door%22&oq=%22there%27s+someone%27s+at+the+door%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...1394.8377.0.9277.7.7.0.0.0.0.620.3814.4-2j5.7.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..3.3.1690...30i10.naQe-4F0pis

Comment: It's would be fine without "there's"... You can definitely say "Someone's at the door"... perhaps that's what they were trying to write. In this case, it is short for "Someone is at the door.".

Comment: Yes it sounded strange to me, but then I thought "maybe there is a rule I do not know.". Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transcription in the image is wrong.

It's likely an error on the part of the editors.

It should read in one of the two ways:

> Now there's someone at the door.
>   Now someone's at the door.

Combining the two doesn't work.

In either case, the word being contracted is "is".

Leaving it un-contracted is also perfectly fine:

> There is someone at the door.
>   Someone is at the door.

Comment: One context where one could use this unusual construct would be if the second _'s_ was forming a possessive, as in: _Now there's someone's dog at the door._ But clearly that's not what's intended in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly true! Nice point.

Comment: In my part of the country *There's someone's at the door* or *There's someone's been hurt* would be colloquially normal instances of relative clauses, because we employ the null relativizer even when it represents the subject of the relative clause: "There's this guy lives two houses down the street."

Comment: @StoneyB That's certainly worth noting but with the caveat that no text should be teaching that variant as "standard".

Comment: @StoneyB Written that way or just spoken that way?

Comment: @StoneyB As I know you as a generous person, would you please explain what you said in your comment a little more. But in a way a non-nativer can understand?

Comment: @user3169 Well, if you transcribed it you'd write it that way.

Comment: @sina In relative clause where the relativizer (*that* or a *wh-* pronoun) stands for anything other than the subject of the clause, it can be dropped: *the man [who] I saw*. Some linguists call this 'absent' relativizer the "null-relativizer". Many dialects, including that I grew up speaking, allow this dropping with subject relativizers, too: *the man [who] owns the bar on the corner*.

Comment: @StoneyB I knew this rule. I learnt it this way: if the relative pronoun is the subject of the clause we can not delete it, but if it is the object of the clause we can drop it. And here I learnt in some American dialects, it is omitable too. Thank you a lot. This is me after learning what you thaught me:☺

Comment: @StonyB I also remebered this: we can shorten a relative clause by dropping relative clause and the verb be together, and turn it into an adjective clause. But if there is no to be verb and we are dropping the relative pronoun, we should change the verb to a gerund. So when the relative pronoun is the subject, it can be dropped provided that we turn it into an adjective phrase. I am happy to learn a new rule for dropping a relative pronoun.